# Problema ao selecionar checkbox php

Tags: php, mysql

Boas

Estou com o seguinte problema eu estou a inserir múltiplos dados através de checkbox essa parte já esta a funcionar agora queria fazer a validação para marcar a caixa dos que já estao inseridos na base de dados mas não estou a conseguir ficam todos marcados.

Código

```
 <?php 
 $result_cat=mysql_query("select * from colecoes where activo=1");
 while($row_cat=mysql_fetch_object($result_cat)){
 ?>
 <div style="float: left; margin: 5px 5px 5px 0px;"><input type="checkbox" <?php // if($_REQUEST['categoria'] == $row_cat->categoria_slug) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> name="categoria[]" value="<?php echo $row_cat->slug; ?>" /> <?php echo $row_cat->titulo; ?></div>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Tabela categorias produtos

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categorias_estabelecimentos` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`estabelecimento_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`categoria_slug` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar da seguinte maneira (já fiz de acordo com o código que você forneceu, somente fiz as alterações necessárias, teste e nos informe do resultado):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="categoria[]" <?= $_REQUEST['categoria'] === $row_cat->categoria_slug ? 'checked' : ''?>  value="<?= $row_cat->slug ?>" /> <?= $row_cat->titulo ?>
```

---

Modificado de acordo com as informações passadas pelo usuário:

```
 <?php 
 $result_cat=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM colecoes WHERE activo=1');
 while($row_cat=mysql_fetch_object($result_cat)) {
     $result_cat_atual = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categorias_estabelecimentos WHERE estabelecimento_id = ID AND categoria_slug = $row_cat->categoria_slug");//Modificar o id 
 ?>
 <div style="float: left; margin: 5px 5px 5px 0px;">
    <input type="checkbox" <?= mysql_num_rows($result_cat_atual) > 0 ? 'checked' : '' ?> name="categoria[]" value="<?= $row_cat->slug ?>" /> <?= $row_cat->titulo; ?>
 </div>

<?php 
}
?>
```

Comment: Aparecem todas selecionadas

Comment: Então por que essa expressão -> $_REQUEST['categoria'] === $row_cat->categoria_slug, é verdadeira. Qual seria a expressão ou com o que você precisaria comparar para analisar se o check deveria ou não estar selecionado?

Comment: Eu preciso que ele verifique na base dados referente a um produto quais são as categorias que tem lá inseridas e apresentar como selecionadas

Comment: Tá e qual seria essa tabela e qual seria o campo?

Comment: Editei o artigo e coloquei a estrutura da tabela

Comment: Cara tá meio confuso, o que seria sua tabela colecoes ali em cima, qual seu vinculo com categorias_estabelecimentos? o $_REQUEST['categoria'], precisaria ser comparado com qual tabela afinal para se chegar ao resultado do 'checked' que você necessitária? Você tira esse estabelecimento_id de algum lugar? Como funciona sua lógica? É apenas um checked para todo o estabelecimento ou pode ser múltiplo?

Comment: A tabela colecoes e onde vou buscar as categorias para as listar juntamente com a opção para selecionar eu preciso de comparar na tabela categorias_estabelecimentos o campo categoria_slug pelo estabelecimento_id e mostrar os que estão selecionados

Comment: @CésarSousa Tente com as alterações que postei agora. Não pude testar, qualquer erro avise...

Comment: Funcionou certinho obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @CésarSousa Disponha